# Return a value in function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if the "candyName" is equal to the inventory's candy, then compare the candy's "inStock" to its "weeklyAverage" and then return true or false based on the "inStock" being larger or smaller than the "weeklyAverage". It keeps coming up undefined (instead of true or false). What am I doing wrong?

```
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function orderCandy(stock, average) {
  if (stock < average) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

function checkCandy(candy, inputCandy) {
  if (candy === inputCandy) {
    let inStock = candy.inStock;
    let weeklyAverage = candy.weeklyAverage;
    return orderCandy(inStock, weeklyAverage);
  }
}

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy (inventory, candyName) {
  let order;
  for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    let selectedCandy =  inventory[i];
    return checkCandy(selectedCandy.name, candyName);
  }
}

shouldWeOrderThisCandy (inventory, "Milk Duds");
```

Comment: That for loop will not run through all the inventory since it will always `return` the first function call. Since there's no match, `checkCandy` returns nothing, i.e. `undefined`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9mex5vp4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works as you would expect, your if test is in the wrong place

```
 let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function orderCandy(stock, average) {
  if (stock < average) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

function checkCandy(candy, inputCandy) {
    let inStock = candy.inStock;
    let weeklyAverage = candy.weeklyAverage;
    return orderCandy(inStock, weeklyAverage);
}

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy (inventory, candyName) {
  let order;
  for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    let selectedCandy =  inventory[i];
    if (selectedCandy.candy==candyName) {
    return checkCandy(selectedCandy, candyName);
    }
  }
}

shouldWeOrderThisCandy (inventory, "Milk Duds");
```

If it works as you planned accept the answer as I think you can't upvote